# How to show views on top of the Navigation Bar from within a child-linked view

Tags: ios, swiftui, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to have a sliding side menu cover the screen as well as the navigation bar. I was following [this tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/side-menu-hamburger-menu-in-swiftui/) to achieve it, and it works well when you have the `NavigationView` declared within the actual view so you can embed it *outside* your `NavigationView` as a sibling in a `ZStack`.

However, anytime I try to pull this view in from a NavigationLink, the views on the sliding menu are "visible" while also blocked by the navigation bar and its views. Any ideas on how to fix this?

#### Side Menu code:

```swift
struct SlidingSideMenu<Content: View>: View {
  let width: CGFloat
  let isOpen: Bool
  let menuClose: () -> Void
  let content: Content
  
  init(width: CGFloat, isOpen: Bool, menuClose: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.width = width
    self.isOpen = isOpen
    self.menuClose = menuClose
    self.content = content()
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      GeometryReader { _ in
        EmptyView()
      }
      .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.3))
      .opacity(self.isOpen ? 1.0 : 0.0)
      .animation(Animation.easeIn.delay(0.25))
      .onTapGesture {
        self.menuClose()
      }
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
      HStack {
        MenuContent(menuClose: menuClose) {
          self.content
        }
        .frame(width: self.width)
        .background(Color.white)
        .offset(x: self.isOpen ? 0 : -self.width)
        .animation(.default)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        
        Spacer()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Working:

```swift
struct MainDetailsView: View {
  @State var menuOpen: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
          Text("Page Content")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .navigationBarTitle("Nav title")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: { self.openMenu() }) {
          Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 25))
            .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading))
      }
      
      SlidingSideMenu(width: 270,
               isOpen: self.menuOpen,
               menuClose: self.openMenu){
        VStack{
          Text("Side Menu Content")
          Spacer()
        }
      }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
    }
  }
  
  func openMenu() {
    self.menuOpen.toggle()
  }
}


struct MainDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    MainDetailsView()
  }
}
```

[Working GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO5r7.gif)

#### Not Working:

```swift
struct ParentNavView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      NavigationLink(
      destination: MainDetailsView()) {
        Text("N A V I G A T E")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct MainDetailsView: View {
  @State var menuOpen: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      // NavView removed
        ScrollView {
          Text("Page Content")
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .navigationBarTitle("Nav title")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: { self.openMenu() }) {
          Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 25))
            .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading))
      
      SlidingSideMenu(width: 270,
               isOpen: self.menuOpen,
               menuClose: self.openMenu){
        VStack{
          Text("Side Menu Content")
          Spacer()
        }
      }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
    }
  }
  
  func openMenu() {
    self.menuOpen.toggle()
  }
}

struct MainDetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ParentNavView()
  }
}
```

[Not working GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DiJ9.gif)